# From a local branch, git push to a different remote branch

Tags: git

I have two remote branches remote/A, remote/B. I pulled them locally and have two branches A, B. Now I modified B and wanted to push it to remote/A. How do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your remote is named `origin`

```
git push origin B:A
```